# R - Apply a function to specific column in a list of similar data.frames

Tags: r, vectorization, lapply

I am making a list of data.frames like so:

`simulation_data <- vector( mode = "list", length = length(subgroups_a))`

`for( A in subgroups_a) {
  simulation_data[['A']] <- 
    paste0(dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT a, b, c, date FROM t WHERE a = ", A))
}`

In general, how do I apply a function to a specific column which is the same across each data.frame in the list?

My specific situation is that I need to apply `ymd()` to the `date` column of each data.frame in `simulation_data`.  My work-around currently is to just update the column each time in the `for` loop like so:
 `simulation_inv[['A']]['dt'] <- ymd(simulation_inv[['A']]['dt'])`, 
but I'd like to vectorize it if possible.

I can't figure out how to use `lapply` to do this, and perhaps there is an even better solution.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps -

```
DT1 = data.frame(A=20130101:20130103,B=letters[1:3])
DT2 = data.frame(A=20130104:20130105,B=letters[4:5])
l = list(DT1,DT2)

l2 <- lapply(l, function(x) cbind(x,as.Date(as.character(x$A),'%Y%m%d')))
```

Where `l` looks like -

```
> l
[[1]]
         A B
1 20130101 a
2 20130102 b
3 20130103 c

[[2]]
         A B
1 20130104 d
2 20130105 e
```

And `l2` looks like -

```
> l2
[[1]]
         A B as.Date(as.character(x$A), "%Y%m%d")
1 20130101 a                           2013-01-01
2 20130102 b                           2013-01-02
3 20130103 c                           2013-01-03

[[2]]
         A B as.Date(as.character(x$A), "%Y%m%d")
1 20130104 d                           2013-01-04
2 20130105 e                           2013-01-05
```

Using this same basic approach, you could also overwrite your earlier column, or assign a nicer column name, etc.

Comment: OK, that is a major improvement (down to 2 lines of code with the removal of the original column), but now I still have the extra column I need to remove.  I'm really after doing this process in one elegant line if possible.

Comment: Define 'one elegant line'. You can do whatever you want inside the `lapply`, for example `data.frame(
    A = as.Date(as.character(x$A),'%Y%m%d'),
    B = x$B
  )`

Comment: In your last sentence you implied that you could overwrite the earlier column with your approach.  I tried doing that (overwriting the column in one line without the ``cbind`` step), but still couldn't figure it out.  With your comment, I now see that I can just redefine the whole data.frame(s) inside of ``lapply``, which is cool, so that may be my one-line solution.  By elegant, I mean to apply a simple function on one column of a list of data.frames (without re-defining the whole data.frames).

Comment: Related (deleted) [SO question](http://news.mrdwab.com/2012/12/04/what-exactly-is-elegant-code-in-r/) ;-)

Comment: @StatSandwich, you could also use `transform`: `l2 <- lapply(l, function(x) transform(x, A = as.Date(as.character(A),'%Y%m%d')))`

Comment: Thanks Ananda!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I've heard, but can't relate to the elegance argument.  Usually when someone says a piece of code is elegant, I agree: Concise, no wasted computing effort.  And faster than other solutions, but that's almost always correlated with the first 2.  Readability is usually irrelevant, imo:  If I see elegant code, and can't read it, it just means I need to learn that library, and that's exactly what lead me to learn ``plyr``, ``data.table``, ``reshape2``, etc.  In other news, I don't know how I've made it this far without using ``transform``.